# Phonegap/Cordova cross platform architecture and single code base

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am building a product using Web Api for the backend and AngularJS on the client side, expecting to launch in a couple of months. All logic is fairly well separated from the client.

Being the sole developer (and marketing, sales, etc) I am very keen on maximizing efficiency and therefore looking at Cordova to handle the mobile app side of things. I have never done any iOs/Android development, but am very quick at picking up new languages and environments so I do not consider that my primary barrier to entry, but I am more concerned with duplication of work effort.

My question is thus; would approaching a small-ish application with the intent of having a single code base by way of Cordova be the right method? I am concerned about having to deal with 3 types of styling to handle iOS/Android menus and slight UI differences between web and mobile applications. Do I just litter with my code with a whole bunch of if(iOS) menu=a, elseif(Android) menu=b, else menu=c ?

Or, would trying to keep the clients as thin as possible and writing native Android/iOS apps be a smarter approach? Here my only real issue is extra effort of maintaining three code bases for the clients.

I've done a lot of reading around and while the opinions seem to be pretty split, no one focuses on the complexity of maintaining multiple code bases with thin clients versus the coding overhead of handling styling with one code base across multiple platforms.

Thanks for your input,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Months later... I am deep into development of the app and it's going swimmingly. I ended up using Cordova with Ionic-Framework and it does exactly what I want. Ionic handles the native look & feel cleanly without a ton of extra work, and everything seems to going well with Cordova. Even better... with 5 minutes of extra work I can easily re-use all of my code for a mobile web app accessible from any browser. Highly recommend

**Ionic Framework**

Answer (score 1):

This is very opinion based, so will be closed pretty soon.

Few years ago I worked for a software house which had a few strong applications in web and desktop versions. Around 2011 it became clear that we had to addressed mobile market as well. The company is quite small so we could not afford native multi-channel development back then. Our primary competence was in Java, JSF and JavaScript (to make the list really short). Moreover, few of the JS technologies we used supported mobile pretty well.

We have evaluated a number of approaches and finally decided to go with PhoneGap (name before Cordova). We used native capabilities like GPS, database, camera (videos/photos), sound recording, compass etc.

We used another JS-based library to make the look-and-feel "more native".

To the best of my knowledge, we never had anything like

```
if (context.iPhone) { doThis(); } else { doThat(); }
```

and I was very deep in code.

We wrote a few of our own Cordova plugins for iOS and Android in parallel (I think it was unzipping). They worked over the same JS API.

Main problem that we had is that the app, well, was not native. You have UI lags despite everything, not the native look-and-feel. The app was still pretty good, but comparing to analogous apps by the bulti-million market leader, you could really tell the difference. However, our app was quite heavy on graphics (GIS/mapping client).

So it is an extremely hard question which may have very heavy consequences, if you make the wrong choice. If your app has to be "sexy", then at some point of time you may find yourself banging against the limits of what the boxed HTML5 app can do.

If your app is per definition something not-so-sparkling (let's take the corporate world of forms-to-fill-to-save-in-db), then you may never reach the limits.

You ask "is it smart". This is impossible to answer without knowing the goal function you're trying to smartoptimize. Are you trying to reduce costs? Shorten time-to-market? Then Cordova (or other hybrid tehchology) may be a very good choice for the short-term tactic decision. Are you planning something long-term? Emphasize on quality? Then you might want to invest into learning native development early.

From what I read in your question, me personally, I'd give it a try. Build something small, with few features but usable, and see how it works. You'll get to know the technology (which is not too difficult) and would be able to consider the next steps having something in the hand. I know cases when people did this, with many outcomes - staying with PhoneGap, switching to another tech as well as raising more money and doing native apps for iOS and Android.

Good luck and best wishes.

Comment: Thanks lexicore. I know it's a bit opinion based but your experience is exactly what I was looking for in determining which route to go. I suppose you're right in that I have nothing to lose if once I finish the web app I just try to go ahead and throw it into Cordova to see if it's usable with minimal tweaks. Also looking at Ionic as a way to branch off what I already have, keep most of the logic in Angular, and just change a bit of the html to get a native feel.

Comment: @JoshuaOhana If you are building something vanilla(standard) not very jazzy app, you can have look at dojo MOBILE toolkit it has prebuilt themes(CSS) for android/IOS/Windows. Link for dojo mobile over [here](https://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile). Also there is `Sencha Touch` which is quite popular.